# Updating Pods not working which were working previously has stopped working

Tags: macos, github, terminal, cocoapods, homebrew

Hello i m trying to update the pods in my existing project and it has been 1 week we are not able to update any pods and we have also removed all the firewall and having full access to the network but still we are facing the same issue which is as follow

Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
[!] Failed to connect to GitHub to update the CocoaPods/Specs specs repo - Please check if you are offline, or that GitHub is down

[!] Your Podfile has had smart quotes sanitised. To avoid issues in the future, you should not use TextEdit for editing it. If you are not using TextEdit, you should turn off smart quotes in your editor of choice.

And also some problem persist is my project get full of error when i try to update.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Feb 2018 weak cryptographic standards removed.

Here a note: https://github.com/blog/2507-weak-cryptographic-standards-removed

To solve this, first you need to **update** `openssl`, then `ruby`, then `cocoapods`.

```
$ which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl

$ openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016

$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

$ brew update

$ brew install openssl

$ brew upgrade openssl

`` If you need to have this software first in your PATH run: echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

$ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ source ~/.bash_profile

$ which openssl
/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl

$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017

$ brew install rbenv ruby-build

$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ source ~/.bash_profile

$ rbenv install --list

Available versions:

  1.9.3-p429
  1.9.3-p448
  1.9.3-p484
  1.9.3-p545
  1.9.3-p547
  1.9.3-p550
  1.9.3-p551
  2.0.0-dev
  2.0.0-preview1
  2.0.0-preview2
  2.0.0-rc1
  2.0.0-rc2
  2.0.0-p0
  2.0.0-p195
  2.0.0-p247
  2.0.0-p353
  2.0.0-p451
  2.0.0-p481
  2.0.0-p576
  2.0.0-p594
  2.0.0-p598
  2.0.0-p643
  2.0.0-p645
  2.0.0-p647
  2.0.0-p648
  2.1.0-dev
  2.1.0-preview1
  2.1.0-preview2
  2.1.0-rc1
  2.1.0
  2.1.1
  2.1.2
  2.1.3
  2.1.4
  2.1.5
  2.1.6
  2.1.7
  2.1.8
  2.1.9
  2.1.10
  2.2.0-dev
  2.2.0-preview1
  2.2.0-preview2
  2.2.0-rc1
  2.2.0
  2.2.1
  2.2.2
  2.2.3
  2.2.4
  2.2.5
  2.2.6
  2.2.7
  2.2.8
  2.2.9
  2.3.0-dev
  2.3.0-preview1
  2.3.0-preview2
  2.3.0
  2.3.1
  2.3.2
  2.3.3
  2.3.4
  2.3.5
  2.3.6
  2.4.0-dev
  2.4.0-preview1
  2.4.0-preview2
  2.4.0-preview3
  2.4.0-rc1
  2.4.0
  2.4.1
  2.4.2
  2.4.3
  2.5.0-dev
  2.5.0-preview1
  2.5.0-rc1
  2.5.0
  2.6.0-dev
  2.6.0-preview1


$ rbenv install 2.1.0
$ rbenv install 2.5.0

$ rbenv versions
* system (set by /Users/username/.rbenv/version)
  2.5.0

$ ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]

$ rbenv global 2.5.0

$ rbenv versions
  system
* 2.5.0 (set by /Users/username/.rbenv/version)

$ ruby --version
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin16.0]

$ gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin

$ which pod
/usr/local/bin/pod

$ pod --version
1.4.0
```

Now, you try updating pod

```
$ pod update
```

Comment: Just updated my answer you may try again and let me know its worked for you?